# android and server secure communication

Tags: android, security, webserver

> In the end I knew that nothing will be their to help me other than the
>   Expert Advices of **SO community**

.I have seen some other questions asked here on stackoverflow about this same thing,but nothing made me clear. I have an android app which is obtaining some registration id from GCM server ,then I want to do some further progress in the development process.However when I came across the security factor, I came to know that my problem is similar to this

- [One of the Question  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196292/what-are-consequences-of-having-gcm-sender-id-being-exposed)

Now, the problem is I want to verify that every time somebody is making requests on my server; then I must be able to know that it is coming from my application.I  also read of using **SSL**, **OAuth** from other resources over internet,but  I have not used it before and I am a complete newbie.I want to integrate in my android devices.If there are some other alternatives please suggest.

---

The thing that my **.apk** will be easliy decompiled is not letting me do anything. My **SENDER_ID**,can easily be retrieved,I will not be able to use some hashing functionality it can be cracked.Whatever way I am thinking to make life harder for the attacker,I am reaching up to the conclusion that nothing is there to stop him/her

---

Some links and examples to implement the functionality may help.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use HTTPS for server communication and use [verfiying back end calls from android](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html).

> You use the GoogleAuthUtil class, available through Google Play
>   services, to retrieve a string called an “ID Token”. You send the
>   token to your back end and your back end can use it to quickly and
>   cheaply verify which app sent it and who was using the app.

Comment: I have seen sites and softwares, those are encrypting the apks, what are they using? and Can they not be decrypted?